# Regex is eating too much stuff

Tags: java, regex

So I recently opened a question and ended up solving it by using a regex.   The regex I used essentially ate ALL my non-english characters.

Let me retry this:

I want to eat all non-keyboard characters that may exist in a string

the regex that I'm using is:

```
[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]
```

However this turns stuff like

10/10/2012 10:51:25 AM

into

```
10102012105125AM
```

Is there some way to easily exclude all alt-code characters from a string with replaceALL and leave keyboard characters like % / \ : and others intact?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us what keyboard layout you're interested in.

Comment: From your question, it's not obvious to me which characters you do and don't want; you might want to read through http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html, which -- in addition to most likely answering your question -- will give you more precise terminology to work with in formulating your question.

Comment: Keyboard layout is just a simple US keyboard (101 key?  Whatever the standard is).   

My question ended up being incorrectly stated, the things I thought were spaces were not spaces... they were weird non-space space characters (Alt+0255 comes to mind I think?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to save only the ASCII characters. The character range `[ -~]` will achieve that. If you also want whitespace chars, you can add them in: `[ -~\s]`.

```
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("[^ -~\\s]+", ""));
```

Comment: Can you give me this as source as I'm not really too great with regex?

Answer (score 1):

To remove all non-ASCII characters:

```
String mystring = <your_input_string>;
mystring.replaceAll("[^ -~\\s]+", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `\p{Print}`? It matches all printable characters, that sounds like exactly what you need.